# Some "can't find" issues, but the program in running fine

Tags: c++

after some pretty fanatic jumbled thingies i successfully managed to run FreeGlue with GLEW.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#define WINDOW_TITLE_PREFIX "Chapter 1"

int CurrentWidth = 800,
        CurrentHeight = 600,
        WindowHandle = 0;

unsigned FrameCount = 0;

void Initialize(int, char*[]);
void InitWindow(int, char*[]);
void ResizeFunction(int, int);
void RenderFunction(void);
void TimerFunction(int);
void IdleFunction(void);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        Initialize(argc, argv);

        glutMainLoop();

        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void Initialize(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        GLenum GlewInitResult;

        InitWindow(argc, argv);

        GlewInitResult = glewInit();

        if (GLEW_OK != GlewInitResult) {
                fprintf(
                        stderr,
                        "ERROR: %s\n",
                        glewGetErrorString(GlewInitResult)
                );
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        fprintf(
                stdout,
                "INFO: OpenGL Version: %s\n",
                glGetString(GL_VERSION)
        );

        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
}

void InitWindow(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        glutInit(&argc, argv);

        glutInitContextVersion(3, 3);
        glutInitContextFlags(GLUT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE);
        glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);

        glutSetOption(
                GLUT_ACTION_ON_WINDOW_CLOSE,
                GLUT_ACTION_GLUTMAINLOOP_RETURNS
        );

        glutInitWindowSize(CurrentWidth, CurrentHeight);

        glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);

        WindowHandle = glutCreateWindow(WINDOW_TITLE_PREFIX);

        if(WindowHandle < 1) {
                fprintf(
                        stderr,
                        "ERROR: Could not create a new rendering window.\n"
                );
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        glutReshapeFunc(ResizeFunction);
        glutDisplayFunc(RenderFunction);
        glutIdleFunc(IdleFunction);
        glutTimerFunc(0, TimerFunction, 0);
}

void ResizeFunction(int Width, int Height)
{
        CurrentWidth = Width;
        CurrentHeight = Height;
        glViewport(0, 0, CurrentWidth, CurrentHeight);
}

void RenderFunction(void)
{
        ++FrameCount;

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        glutSwapBuffers();
        glutPostRedisplay();
}

void IdleFunction(void)
{
        glutPostRedisplay();
}

void TimerFunction(int Value)
{
        if (0 != Value) {
                char* TempString = (char*)
                        malloc(512 + strlen(WINDOW_TITLE_PREFIX));

                sprintf(
                        TempString,
                        "%s: %d Frames Per Second @ %d x %d",
                        WINDOW_TITLE_PREFIX,
                        FrameCount * 4,
                        CurrentWidth,
                        CurrentHeight
                );

                glutSetWindowTitle(TempString);
                free(TempString);
        }

        FrameCount = 0;
        glutTimerFunc(250, TimerFunction, 1);
}
```

code is pretty simple, it runs perfectly, but this is showing some can't find errors. Can anyone suggest me where to look at for this issue?

```
'OGL_test1.exe': Loaded 'E:\Visual studio 2010\Projects\OGL_test1\Debug\OGL_test1.exe', Symbols loaded.
'OGL_test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'OGL_test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'OGL_test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'OGL_test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\freeglut.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'OGL_test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'OGL_test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'OGL_test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\lpk.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'OGL_test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\usp10.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'OGL_test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'OGL_test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'OGL_test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'OGL_test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'OGL_test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'OGL_test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'OGL_test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\opengl32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'OGL_test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\glu32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'OGL_test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ddraw.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'OGL_test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dciman32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'OGL_test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\setupapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'OGL_test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cfgmgr32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'OGL_test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'OGL_test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'OGL_test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\devobj.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'OGL_test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'OGL_test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmm.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'OGL_test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\glew32.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'OGL_test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
'OGL_test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'OGL_test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'OGL_test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\atiglpxx.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'OGL_test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\atioglxx.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'OGL_test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'OGL_test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ws2_32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'OGL_test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nsi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'OGL_test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\atigktxx.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'OGL_test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\aticfx32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'OGL_test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\atiadlxy.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'OGL_test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wintrust.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'OGL_test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\crypt32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'OGL_test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msasn1.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'OGL_test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Download Manager\idmmkb.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1444) has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).
The program '[5464] OGL_test1.exe: Native' has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those aren't errors, just information that the runtime couldn't fine the debug information for various DLLs. Don't worry, they aren't needed.

Comment: But ,why they would they even show up? I am curious about the inner details.

Comment: @iamcreasy: Well, because the runtime is loading those DLLs when your program runs. And as it apperently runs in debug mode, it will try to find debug information for those DLLs, so you can get better diagnostics should something fail.

Comment: @iamcreasy : because you're trying to debug the app and it's trying to load the necessary symbols for you to do that

Comment: @iamcreasy Because it might provide some helpful information to people who need it?

Comment: What can I do to circumvent this issue? Any kind of setting "path" with my project?

Comment: @iamcreasy: Why do you want to circumvent that? It's only output in the debug window anyways...

Comment: @andrei can you please explain, how do you conclude that this missing dll files is a issue that's related to debugging? Dont we need to have dll files on Built time?

Comment: @xeo I am thinking in this way "If they are asked, then they are being requested by some component. The component is still working fine for some reason. But, there should be a reason why they were called in the first place. It may not be important. But I want to know how to circumvent this issue."

Comment: @iamcreasy : you are not missing dlls, you are missing symbols. Symbols you probably don't need anyway. You shouldn't really care about them if you don't plan to debug the MS dlls. Focus on errors and warnings, not these output messages.

Comment: @iamcreasy: The `.pdb` files are not requested by the DLLs. `.pdb` stands for "Program debug database" and is used by the Visual Studio debugger to display debug information.

Comment: @iamcreasy: The reason was explained. Circumventing, in this case, is not appropriate -- the debugger is simply being noisy. It won't affect your program, and your user won't see it. It won't even happen for a release build. (I _do_ admire your approach: you are asking all the right questions. However in this case the answer really is "don't worry about it").

Comment: @iamcreasy : they are asked by the debugger, not by your program

Answer (score 1):

You can download the symbol files from Microsoft, see

[How to use a symbol server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8ttk8zy.aspx)

Comment: what is symbol and symbol server?

Comment: @iamcreasy - The files that the debugger says are missing. If you want to, you can download them from Microsoft's server.

Comment: Yes, thank you. But, I dont know what symbol and symbol server is. Can you please explain a little? I am more interested in why not how.